# Were informed or just informed?

Tags: tense

I'm wondering to what tense this constructions belongs to? I think
it is Past Simple. But I thought that if in the sentence we use any verb the auxiliary verb was / were no longer using? Just ad ED in the end of the verb.

For example :

> I was informed.

Why we use WAS?

I thought *was* and *were* are using only when we have no any verb in sentence.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is in passive form. and happened in the past
( past passive tense)

When you say "I was informed" it is in past passive tense and means somebody informed you of something. But when you say "I informed" it is in simple past tense and  means you yourself informed others of something.

Answer (score 0):

The [passive voice](https://www.ego4u.com/en/cram-up/grammar/passive) is being used in your sentence

> **Passive voice** is used when the focus is on the action. It is not
>   important or not known, however, who or what is performing the action.

**Form of Passive**

> Subject + finite form of to be + Past Participle

We use the **past form** of to be [was/were] because the action took place in the past.

Example: Yesterday I **was informed** by my boss that I **was fired**.